# Abstract class cannot be constructed: cellshop

Tags: deployment

```
public abstract class cellshop
{
cellshop()
{
system.debug('jjjjjj');
}
private abstract void cost();
void change()
{system.debug('iiiii');}

public class ad extends cellshop
{
private override void cost()
{system.debug('cell cost7872');
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you have posted compiles and so would this code using it:

```
cellshop.ad x = new cellshop.ad();
```

or this:

```
cellshop x = new cellshop.ad();
```

but this:

```
cellshop x = new cellshop();
```

will result in the message in the title of your question. An instance of `cellshop` has no implementation of the `cost` method and so you are protected from trying to use it; an instance of `ad` has that method provided and so is allowed.

From Wikipedia [Abstract type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type):

> In programming languages, an abstract type is a type in a nominative
>   type system which cannot be instantiated directly. Abstract types are
>   also known as existential types. An abstract type may provide no
>   implementation, or an incomplete implementation. Often, abstract types
>   will have one or more implementations provided separately, for
>   example, in the form of concrete subclasses which can be instantiated.
>   It may include abstract methods or abstract properties that are
>   shared by its subtypes.

Comment: @sekhar If you sometimes want to instantiate (create) `cellshop` then don't make it `abstract`. You can `extend` non-abstract classes - see e.g. [Can a non-abstract class be extended (inherited from) in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585057/can-a-non-abstract-class-be-extended-inherited-from-in-java). Apex and Java have many similarities.

Comment: @sekhar Note that in Apex "The virtual definition modifier declares that this class allows extension and overrides. You cannot override a method with the override keyword unless the class has been defined as virtual.". Google for examples.